# Me da error al crear proyecto

Tags: ionic2, ionic-framework

Estoy trabajando con Ionic me da error al momento de crear un proyecto, muestro imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Git CLI not found on your PATH. It must be installed to connect this app to Ionic.

Comment: @Trauma Que de malo hay que muestre el error en una imagen no le veo nada de malo.

Comment: @Trauma si deseas cierralo

Comment: ¿ Tienes GIT instalado en la máquina y colocado su directorio en el *PATH* ?

Comment: Si tengo instalado GIT, no se como colocar el directorio en el path,

Comment: Llevo 20 años sin usar el Güindo$ ese, ya no estoy seguro de como se hace. Mira https://stackoverflow.com/a/28545224 ¡ Que tiempos los del `autoexec.bat` y `config.sys` ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Logre solucionarlo el problema que tenía era que estaba instalando primero Ionic y después Cordova y además no lo estaba haciendo a nivel global.

**Lo correcto es instalar primeramente Cordoba y posteriormente Ionic.**

Este fue el orden que utilice.

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova
$ sudo npm install -g ionic
```

Referencia [Chapter 2: Installation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/installation.html)

Saludos.